# proving that $S_{2n}=3n^2+n,S_{2n+1}=3n^2+5n+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $a_n=\frac{1}{2}(-1)^n(2-n)+\frac{3n}{2}$

Need to show that $S_{2n}=3n^2+n,S_{2n+1}=3n^2+5n+1$.

I tired to separate $a_n$ to odd and even but something went wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider, that the induction step goes from n to n+2 in this case ?

Comment: we didn't learn induction and don't even know what that means.

Comment: But you know the formula $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, I think.

Comment: arithmetic progression yes. but the $(-1)^n$ term is what makes it hard.

Comment: Or was the problem to calculate the progressions ?

Comment: so first i need to use $a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$ then :$n^*=2n$ and $n^2=2n+1$ and for odd and even separately right?

Comment: i guess the calculation part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$A_{2n-1}=1+3+\dots+2n-1=n^2,$$
$$A_{2n}=2+4+\dots+2n=n^2+n.$$
Also, 
\begin{eqnarray}
a_n&=&\frac{(-1)^n}{2}(2-n)+\frac{3n}{2},\\
a_n&=&\frac{(-1)^n}{2}\cdot 2-\frac{(-1)^n}{2}\cdot n+\frac{3n}{2},\\
a_n&=&\frac{(-1)^n}{2}\cdot 2+\frac{3-(-1)^n}{2}\cdot n,\\
a_n&=&(-1)^n+\frac{3-(-1)^n}{2}\cdot n,
\end{eqnarray}
from where we get $a_{2k-1}=-1+2\cdot(2k-1)$ and $a_{2k}=1+2k$.

Therefore, 
$$a_1+a_3\dots+a_{2n-1}=(-1+2\cdot 1)+(-1+2\cdot 3)+\dots+(-1+2\cdot (2n-1)),$$
$$a_1+a_3\dots+a_{2n-1}=n\cdot (-1)+2\cdot (1+3+\dots+2n-1)=-n+2 A_{2n-1}$$
and similarly
$$a_2+a_4\dots+a_{2n}=(1+2)+(1+4)+\dots+(1+2n),$$
$$a_2+a_4\dots+a_{2n}=n\cdot 1+(2+4+\dots+2n)=n+A_{2n}$$
Finally,
$$S_{2n}=(a_1+a_3\dots+a_{2n-1})+(a_2+a_4+\dots+a_{2n}),$$
$$S_{2n}=(n\cdot(-1)+2\cdot A_{2n-1})+(n\cdot 1+A_{2n}),$$
$$S_{2n}=(-n+2\cdot n^2)+(2n+n^2)=3n^2+n$$

Since $S_{2n+1}=S_{2n}+a_{2n+1}$, $$S_{2n+1}=3n^2+n+4n+1=3n^2+5n+1.$$

Comment: can you elaborate how did you get $A_{2n-1}=1+3+\dots+2n-1=n^2,$
$A_{2n}=2+4+\dots+2n=n^2+n.$ ?

Comment: honestly i didn't get also the other parts..

Comment: $A_{2n}=2\cdot (1+2+\dots+n)=2\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=n(n+1)$ and $A_{2n-1}=(1+2+\dots+2n)-A_{2n}=\frac{2n(2n+1)}{2}-(n^2+n)=2n^2+n-n^2-n=n^2$.

Comment: thanks but how did you get to $2+4+...$ i mean you substitute $n=2$ for $A_{2n}$ because i cant get it. also i can't get the part that you used $k$ where did he come from? can't understand the rest it's too complicated for me but thanks for the effort.

Comment: Every odd number can be expressed as $2k-1$ for some k and every even number can be expressed as $2k$, therefore is $k$ in formula.

Comment: Or, $a_n=1+n$ for even number $n$ and $a_n=-1+2n$,  for odd $n$.

Comment: thanks im trying to understand. can you explain why $a_n=(-1)^n+\frac{3-(-1)^n}{2}n,$?

Comment: wow i got it! thanks a lot!